# React show block with information on hover

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a lot of blocks with items. I want to show item information (block near the item), when user hover on it.
Here is an example:
[First example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Y99d.png)
[Second example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2j3De.png)

Comment: I think you can achieve that using css :hover and sibling selector +:
``.block:hover + .nextBlock { display: block; }``

Comment: Can you share what you've tried so far?

Comment: @SachinSingh, yes, but how I can take information from block which user hovered? Because each block has different information

Comment: Hi @MIkle: I think you can put the information in both blocks. But if you are trying to achieve something on runtime like picking values from hovered block you can make use of React ``onMouseEnter`` and ``onMouseLeave`` synthetic events and ``event.target`` to get the hovered element.

Comment: Show a [mcve], please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this in react by.

```
class nameOfClass extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
     box1Hover:false,
     box2Hover:false,
     box3Hover:false,
     box4Hover:false,
    }
    this.trueDisplay = this.trueDisplay.bind(this)
    this.falseDisplay = this.falseDisplay.bind(this)
  }
  trueDisplay(e){

   this.setState({[e.target.name]:true})
  }
  falseDisplay(e){

   this.setState({[e.target.name]:false})
  }
  render(){
   return(
      <div>
       <div name="box1Hover" onMouseEnter={this.trueHover} onMouseLeave={this.falseHover}>
         ....
          // your on hover content in bellow line 
         {this.state.box1Hover?<h5>Mouse hovering over me</h5>:""}
        ....
       <div>
       <div name="box2Hover" onMouseEnter={this.trueHover} onMouseLeave={this.falseHover}>
         ....
          // your on hover content in bellow line 
         {this.state.box2Hover?<h5>Mouse hovering over me</h5>:""}
        ....
       <div>
       <div name="box3Hover" onMouseEnter={this.trueHover} onMouseLeave={this.falseHover}>
         ....
          // your on hover content in bellow line 
         {this.state.box3Hover?<h5>Mouse hovering over me</h5>:""}
        ....
       <div>
      </div>
   )
  }
}
```

> if you know jquery then you can use tooltip
>   https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tooltip.asp

Comment: Ok, thank's. But how I can do it puttuing this h5 outside the block? Because it would be bad if I have 200+ elements

Comment: @MIkle You can put `{this.state.box1Hover?<h5>Mouse hovering over me</h5>:""}` this line any where outside or inside the box1Hover. It will perform the same. i.e when you hover over box1Hover then that particular <h4> tag will be visible.

Comment: @MIkle have a look to ans i just edited it. See if it help